# How can I find roots of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots

I am interested to find new methods to find roots of polynomials. I know the Ruffini's rule and basics methods to try. But I heared about the Galois Theory and I have a doubt. Does Galois theory help to find roots? I am interested mainly in the applications of the Galois Theory or other methods.

Comment: Galois Theory can tell you whether or not a polynomial has roots expressible in radicals. It does not provide a method for finding roots of all polynomials.

Comment: @GoranMalic That is disappointing.